# smoothing 2D plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some simple plot like this in MATLAB:

```
x = [0:5:25];
y = [1 4 7 9 8 3];
plot(x,y)
```

My question is how can I smooth it? Haven't found any way of doing what I want in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could make use of `spline` as follows

```
x1 = 0:.1:25;
y1 = spline(x,y,x1);
plot(x,y,x1,y1);
```

Comment: Note that this does NOT do smoothing, as you asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *cubic smoothing spline*

```
p  = 1e-2;           % initialize smoothing constant
fn = csaps(x, y, p); % get ppform of the cubic smoothing spline
y1 = ppval(fn, x);   % evaluate piecewise polynomial
```

For comparison:

```
plot(x,y);
hold on;
plot(x, y1, '-r');
```

Comment: Yes. This is one good option. One can also simply do a gaussian blur, using conv to do the work.

Comment: It should be noted that `csaps` requires the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting/) installed.