# Increase resolution in X-axis for an existing x-y graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

In MATLAB, I have an existing set of values for `X,Y` where `X = [0,1,2, ... 255]`, and `Y` is in the range of `-5` to `4`.

When I plot this graph MATLAB, obviously interpolates these values.

I require to increase the resolution of the X-axis to `X = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0. 75, 1 .... 254.75, 255]`.

I am not looking for a simple averaging kind of operation. Rather I want it to be as good as MATLAB which does it very smoothly. Please guide me.

Comment: Smoothing a plot further as you seem to be requesting is described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19442682/2778484).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to know:

1. Matlab doesn't interpolate if you haven't made it interpolate. The figure you see is scalable, so there is no interpolation, at most a line connecting between adjacent dots.
2. If you want to interpolate just use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)....

fore example,

```
 Xnew= 0:0.25:255;
 Ynew=interp1(X,Y,Xnew,'spline');
 plot(Xnew,Ynew);
```

should do.