# Increase data points in signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, interpolation, sampling

I have an input data set of `32` points. Now I want to convert these `32` points to `240` points by averaging the data over the points.

I thought of plotting the `32` sample points which I have and then by approximately plotting the curve and taking data at a higher sampling frequency so as to obtain `240` points.

I am not able to understand how to do this in MATLAB. I took help from some sources, but I was not able to come up with any solution. How can this be done?

In short, I want to convert 'x' samples of discrete data set to 'y' samples of new data set by approximating the signal. Here `x > y` or also `x < y`.

Comment: 'Here x > y and also, x < y.' what? Your problem sounds like [interpolation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/interpolation-1.html)

Comment: @Arpi: I just meant x can be both greater than or less than y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resample` does what you want,

```
newdata = resample(data,240,32);
```

for example :

```
a = 1 : 32;
b = resample(a,240,32);
t = 1 : 32;
t1 = linspace(1,32,240);
plot(t,a);hold on;plot(t1,b,'r');
```

[image]

The noise at the end is probably because of sharp filter, `240/32` is too high.

`resample` does great actually,

```
a = randi(10,[1 100]);
b = resample(a,240,100);
t = 1 : 100;
t1 = linspace(1,100,240);
plot(t,a);hold on;plot(t1,b,'r')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The function which I was searching for so long. :)
And Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: @AbhinavAggarwal You can also do [the same with `interp1`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19442682/2778484), which does not require the Signal Processing Toolbox.  Good answer though! +1