# Calculating the correlation of 2D signals with different sizes

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I am trying to calculate the correlation between two different signals and it works perfect if the signals have the same size. But it gives an error if there size is different. So I am wondering if there is any way that I can change the size of one to the other so they can have the same size? Any Help??

As example:

If signal 1 is a matrix of size `130X9` and signal `2` is another matrix of size `122X12` and they look the same .. so what I need is to scale one of them to the other, so both of them can be of size `130X9`  or `122X12`.

My code:

```
norm_xcorr_mag = @(x,y)(max(abs(xcorr(x,y)))/(norm(x,2)*norm(y,2)));
norm_xcorr_mag(signal1,signal2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `signal processing toolbox`,

```
A = randi(100,[130 9]);
B = randi(100,[122 12]);
MaxRow = max(size(A,1),size(B,1));
MaxCol = max(size(A,2),size(B,2));
NewA = resample(A,MaxRow,size(A,1));
NewB = resample(B,MaxRow,size(B,1));
NewA = resample(NewA',MaxCol,size(A,2))';
NewB = resample(NewB',MaxCol,size(B,2))';
```

`NewA` and `NewB` are both `130x12`

You could also try `intrep1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kamtal,  it is working fine but I need to know how it resample the data from small size to the large one? based on what? and does it affect the signal shape?

Comment: @SMH. there is an example for signal's shape here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817222/increase-data-points-in-signal/26817310#26817310

Comment: @SMH, You could also specify the `order` of filter used in `resample(signal,P,Q,order)` to get more precise interpolation.

Comment: That's perfect .. Thanks Heaps @Kamtal